# adding labels to barchart,coreplot

Tags: ios, core-plot, bar-chart

Hi M getting  problem with adding labels..M adding labels statically by passing array inside a loop and setting positions of x &y-axis..m passing color images array and label array..even here M getting upside down labels and color images..wat the problem might be..down is the code:

```
for( int i=0;i< [PieChartColorDescriptionArray count]; i++)
    {
        UIButton* blueButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [blueButton setFrame:CGRectMake(165+80,65+(40*i),10,20)];
        [blueButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [blueButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth ];
        [blueButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[PieChartButtonImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [blueButton setAutoresizingMask:AUTORESIZEMASK];
        [blueButton setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
        [self.view addSubview:blueButton];
        [blueButton retain];
        UILabel* loLabel1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(178+80,50+(40*i),50,50)];
        [loLabel1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [loLabel1 setTag:101];
        [loLabel1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [loLabel1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        [loLabel1 setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
        [loLabel1 setNumberOfLines:1];
        [loLabel1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]];
        [loLabel1 setText:[PieChartColorDescriptionArray objectAtIndex:i]];
       //loLabel1.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-360.0);
        [loLabel1 setAutoresizingMask:AUTORESIZEMASK];
        [self.view addSubview:loLabel1];

        [loLabel1 retain];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `self.view` the Core Plot hosting view? If so, don't add any subviews to it. Instead, create a hierarchy of views with some sort of container view at the top. Add the hosting view and your labels and buttons as subviews of the container view.

Comment: Hi..Ya ..I have added self.view=hosting view....and trying to do [hosting view addsubview : label] or [self.view addsubview: label]....

Comment: U mean to say I got to create separate UIView and then add graph hosting view and label to it ..as its subviews?? cant we add subviews to graph hosting view??

Comment: Hi Eric Skroch...U were right..thanks for suggestions :)..I got the output..Actually I created UIView *view1..set frame for it..then graph was added to hosting view(set frame for hosting view also) and this hosting view was added to view1..and labels and buttons were directly added to view1..which gave me right output..Thank U